# how to make Android ImageView downloading image gradually

Tags: android, image

I am building an application that downloads and displays several images. Everything is going well.

But i want it display an image as soon as it downloading. Not when its done downloading. I'm pretty sure it's called something like Interlaced, since i use PNGs.

[image: taken from wikipedia]

This is part of code i've done to download and display an image :

```
    private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Bitmap> {

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        ivGambar.setImageBitmap(result);// ivGambar is an ImageView

        pbDetail.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... pa) {
        try {
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(pa[0])
                    .getContent());
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Is it can be done in Android? How?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly, but you can try to read progressively from the URL and then decode the stream even if it is incomplete, then doing it as you read from the stream, storing it in a buffer.

You can use [URL.openStream()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URL.html#openStream%28%29) to get the stream, copy progressively the contents in a byte array (growing it if needed) and then use [BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeByteArray%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options%29) to get the decoded partial bitmap (if the data is enough of course).

You could even use [ByteArrayOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html) as a buffer.

Be careful not to do this too often as it may slow down everything massively.